# Sql Server Data Tools headless build fails with MissingMethodException

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, sql-server-data-tools

Trying to get a build for a visual studio 2010 data tools project working on our build server.  The server is 2008 R2 (64bit) and I have followed the instructions [here](http://sqlproj.com/index.php/2012/03/headless-msbuild-support-for-ssdt-sqlproj-projects/) for installing the necessary prerequisites.  The project builds fine locally on a full VS 2010 install (doesn't it always!) but on the build server I'm seeing the following error (edited for brevity and anonymity):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets(513,5): error MSB4018:
The "SqlBuildTask" task failed unexpectedly. 
 System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<System.String,System.String> Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Build.SqlPropertiesHelper.ParseContributorArgs(System.String)'.
  at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Tasks.Sql.SqlBuildTask.ExecuteValidateModelStep()
  at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Tasks.Sql.SqlBuildTask.ExecuteStep(Func`1 step)
  at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Tasks.Sql.SqlBuildTask.Execute()
  at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
  at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost, TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, TaskHost taskHost, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask, Boolean& taskResult)
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Apologies for self answering but hopefully this helps someone.

I looked in the SqlTasks.targets file and saw the SqlBuildTask originated from the "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DAC\bin\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Tasks.Sql.10.dll" file.  As the build was working locally I compared the versions between there and the build server.  I noticed some DLLs had the same version but others were different.  I tried to reflect in to find where the "missing method" was supposed to reside but gave up and decided to copy the contents of the folder from my dev machine over the same folder on the build server excluding the "en" and "1033" folders.

This seems to have resolved the issue, I can only assume that somewhere in the ridiculous number of separate installs I've had to do on the build server, dlls that are out of step with each other have been introduced and this has caused the problem.

Would be great if someone could properly explain or suggest a more legitimate solution.

Comment: I noticed the SSDT tools can be quite fragile if you have multiple versions installed.  Things like attempting to kick off a build from a command line outside of the Visual Studio command prompt can bring about unexpected issues.  Your best bet would be to clean up the build server and incorporate the external dependencies (binaries and targets) within your build tree.

Comment: We do not have multiple versions installed, though the installs for the build server require both x86 and x64 versions of several MSIs to be installed and doesn't specify any order to install them in.  Good suggestion with regard to incorporating the files into the build tree, but this is a very manual solution and should not be required.

Comment: There are multiple issues on connect.microsoft.com in regards to Tasks.Sql.dll.  Welcome to the club.

Answer (score 0):

There is also an issue with SSDT in Visual Studio if you install SQL Server 2012. Cure for me was to reinstall the latest SSDT after the SQL install. I note the question refers to VS2010 but the SSDT issues seem to be everywhere.

There is some more info here: http://fubnuts.wordpress.com/2013/05/31/fun-with-vs2012-sql-server-projects-and-sql-server-2012/

SSDT download here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/hh297027